# Sql Server reporting error when generating values from query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report parameter which depends on a query from the Dataset. The query needs one parameter and sql server reporting has no parameter drop down

version - Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Report Builder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows the dialog for parameter configuration. You should go to Report -> Data -> Datasets and there choose the data set that needs to be parametrized.